# Problem understanding the gradient of a field.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**
A surface that is described explicitly by an equation of the form $z= f(x,y)$ can be thought as a level surface of the scalar field F defined by the equation 
$ F(x,y,z)= f(x,y)-z$ . Then 
$\nabla F = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} i+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}j-k$.

**Doubt**
 $z= f(x,y)$ implies $ F(x,y,z)= f(x,y)-z=0$. Then gradient is always zero because **if $F$ is identically zero , $\nabla F$ is also zero for all points on the surface**.

Please help.

Comment: I was visiting freshman mathematics , i am having this silly ,annoying doubt.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add another one after you have received valid answers for the first. If one of the answers has resolved your first question, please mark it as accepted and create a new post for your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that the function $F(x,y,z) $ is identically zero. Instead we have a function

$$F: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$$
or $F: U\subset \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$,
and the surface is the set of special points $(x,y,z)$ where $F(x,y,z) = 0$.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please kindly look into it.

Comment: @blueboy well in this case its quadratic in $z$, so you can explicitly write out $f(x,y)$ with the high school formula.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see that’s a problem.

A surface can be described in two different ways, i.e. $z=f(x,y)$ or $F(x,y,z)=0$. Let’s look at the second form. If a point $(x,y,z)$ is on the surface, then $F(x,y,z)$, of course, is zero. Otherwise, this condition does not necessarily hold. Thus, the partial derivatives may not be $0$.

Consider the following example: the plane $z=f(x,y):=x+y$ can also be written as $F(x,y,z):=x+y-z=0$. All gradients $\nabla F = ({\partial F\over \partial x}, {\partial F\over \partial y}, {\partial F\over \partial z}) = (1,1,-1)\ne 0$.

Comment: So if the point is on the surface gradient is zero?

Comment: Because if F is identically zero , $\nabla F$ is also zero .Here F=z-f(x,y)

Comment: @blueboy I don’t think so. I added an example in my answer; please read it if you don’t mind.

Comment: I have edited my question . Please kindly look into it.